# How to make sense of the Kotlin `ClosedFloatingPointRange`?

Tags: kotlin, generics, operator-overloading

The `ClosedFloatingPointRange` seems like a simple interface to a  mathematical interval.

```
public interface ClosedFloatingPointRange<T : Comparable<T>> : ClosedRange<T> {
    override fun contains(value: T): Boolean = lessThanOrEquals(start, value) && lessThanOrEquals(value, endInclusive)
    override fun isEmpty(): Boolean = !lessThanOrEquals(start, endInclusive)

    /**
     * Compares two values of range domain type and returns true if first is less than or equal to second.
     */
    fun lessThanOrEquals(a: T, b: T): Boolean
}
```

The [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/-closed-floating-point-range/) says:

> Represents a range of floating point numbers. Extends ClosedRange
> interface providing custom operation lessThanOrEquals for comparing
> values of range domain type.
>
> This interface is implemented by floating point ranges returned by
> Float.rangeTo and Double.rangeTo operators to achieve IEEE-754
> comparison order instead of total order of floating point numbers.

It seems that in Kotlin the comparison `a <= b` where `a` and `b` are of type `Double` is either the IEEE-754 intuitive comparison where NaN is not comparable, or a comparison by the `Comparable<Double>.compareTo` function. The latter is a total order, meaning that it has some nice algebraic properties, but it allows us to do things that don't make sense - such as define a non-empty interval `[∞, NaN]`. The `ClosedFloatingPointRange` exists to allow the user to provide whatever comparison makes sense for him.

The rules for when `<=` resolves to `compareTo` are explained in the [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html#floating-point-numbers-comparison), but I did not understand them sufficiently to make sense the following implementation from the standard library:

```
private class ClosedDoubleRange(
    start: Double,
    endInclusive: Double
) : ClosedFloatingPointRange<Double> {
    private val _start = start
    private val _endInclusive = endInclusive
    ...

    override fun lessThanOrEquals(a: Double, b: Double): Boolean = a <= b

    override fun contains(value: Double): Boolean = value >= _start && value <= _endInclusive
    override fun isEmpty(): Boolean = !(_start <= _endInclusive)
    ...
```

`ClosedDoubleRange` overrides `lessThanOrEquals` to presumably provide the class with the desired IEEE-754 floating point comparison. So far so good. Now, right after that it overrides `contains` and `isEmpty`, the only callers of `lessThanOrEquals`. Why? On top of that it *seems* that the overriden versions are identical in behavior to the overridees.

But there must be some difference. It makes no sense to override `lessThanEquals` and then never use it. `ClosedDoubleRange` does the same thing. I have a feeling that I am missing something crucial here. It probably has something to do with the resolution rules of `<=` or perhaps the fact that `ClosedDoubleRange` overrides a generic interface?

Comment: `lessThanOrEquals` has to be overridden even if the subtype isn't using it, since it's abstract in the interface. As for why it's defined in the first place when the two functions that rely on it are overridden in both subtypes, you got me. Seems like those two functions should be abstract in the interface, and `lessThanOrEquals` omitted.

Comment: Seen like this it doesn't make much sense. It's probably that someone has left behind a refactor or something. This isn't an interface users of Kotlin are much expected to interact with anyway.

Comment: @al3c It could be. It is silly of me that I did not consider this. Also, it is a quite useful interface - you can instantiate it very easily using expressions as `1.0..2.0`.